# php echo from array_chunk as string

Tags: php, arrays

I want to echo an array_chunk as string, how do I do that ?
here is the code

```
$rt = $this->db->query("SELECT id_reg_pd FROM 043104_kuliahmhs_20152_2a0dc380_temp");
$_datao = array_chunk($rt->result(), 3);
foreach($_datao as $batman => $robin) {
    print_r($robin);
}
```

I want echo id_reg_pd as string.
I have tried tried :

```
echo $robin->id_reg_pd;
```

but get php error like this

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message:  Trying to get property of non-object
```

Here the array from print_r($robin);

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_reg_pd] => 001be76b-4e58-4cea-96cf-fee2d8e0abdc
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_reg_pd] => 001d4fe5-73f5-4bae-b126-1f787ea0104e
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_reg_pd] => 002ab28b-e0b9-464a-89fb-12552512a5d0
        ) 
)
```

Comment: `$robin` is an array of objects, so `$robin[0]->id_reg_pd`, `$robin[1]->id_reg_pd`, `$robin[2]->id_reg_pd` are valid .

Answer (score 0):

Loop over `$robin` and then check

```
foreach($robin as $value)
{
    echo $value->id_reg_pd;
}
```

Comment: you mean foreach inside foreach ? that's a lot of prosses. But I'll try

Comment: @BillyOrigin yes exactly.. You have to

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
   for($i=0;$i<count($_datao);$i++){ 
    $newarr = (array) $robin[$i];
    echo $newarr['id_reg_pd'];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sahil is incorrect.** It is not true that you *must* use a for / foreach loop to achieve your desired result.  `array_column()` works on an array of objects.  If you can use a simple `implode()` call to convert your array to a string, then here is a simple one-liner:

Code ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c965bf292b3245ac6970dfaa329db7bc646d1d94)):

```
$robin=[
    (object)['id_reg_pd'=>'001be76b-4e58-4cea-96cf-fee2d8e0abdc'],
    (object)['id_reg_pd'=>'001d4fe5-73f5-4bae-b126-1f787ea0104e'],
    (object)['id_reg_pd'=>'002ab28b-e0b9-464a-89fb-12552512a5d0']
];
//print_r($robin);  // uncomment to see for yourself
//var_export(array_column($robin,'id_reg_pd'));  // uncomment to see for yourself
echo implode(', ',array_column($robin,'id_reg_pd')); // implode with whatever glue you wish
```

Output:

```
001be76b-4e58-4cea-96cf-fee2d8e0abdc, 001d4fe5-73f5-4bae-b126-1f787ea0104e, 002ab28b-e0b9-464a-89fb-12552512a5d0
```